# Machine to Machine File transfer

Tags: c#

I need to transfer text files located at a location from one machine to another machine through .NET for every one second.
Later again i require to transfer vice-versa.
Please help me how to acheive through C#.NET

Comment: Transferring a file once a second for how long? For what purpose. This might be pretty difficult if the files are large. What have you already tried?

Comment: Are the machines on same or a different network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use Computer class and a Timer for moving file every 1 sec

Answer (score 1):

In case the machines are on the same network, you might also try and work with network shares. Then you could use `\\machine\folder` as destination folder for your files using the normal `File.Copy` method.

Answer (score 1):

To transfer a file from machine A to machine B you could use the [Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9706cfs5.aspx) method. Assuming you have administrative privileges on machine B you could use the following code to copy a file every second from machine A to machine B:

```
ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject(
    new ManualResetEvent(false), 
    (state, timedOut) => 
    {
        // TODO: error handling
        File.Copy("c:\someFile.txt", "\\machineB\c$\someFile.txt", true);
    }, 
    null, 
    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), 
    false);
```

If you don't have administrative privileges on machine B you could use shares:

```
File.Copy("c:\someFile.txt", "\\machineB\someShare\someFile.txt", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an FTP server on each machine, you can use a [C# FTP Client Library](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/ftplib.aspx).

You may also want to consider one of the [P2P libraries](http://swik.net/p2p+Library) out there (no FTP server required).

Whether you can transfer the files in the time available depends on the file size and bandwidth more than the means you use to transfer the files, though some protocols have more overhead than others.

Comment: You need an FTP server configured on each machine.  Then, you add code from the C# FTP Client Library (see link in my answer) to your own program.  That gives you a class that you can use to open an FTP connection to the remote machine and copy files.  There is demo code along with the Client Library that shows exactly how to do it.